# SPContext is null when calling Web Method

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint layouts page in which I have this web method.

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = false)]
        [ScriptMethod]
        public static List<ItemData> GetItems(string SearchTerm)
        {

  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
                    {
                        SPList list =          web.Lists.TryGetList("Data");
                        _documentListId = list.ID;
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

I call this web method with the below code

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "multispr.aspx/GetItems",
        data: JSON.stringify({ SearchTerm: $('#SearchTerm').val() }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (data, status) {
            self.Items(data.d);
            myApp.hidePleaseWait();
        },
        failure: function (data) {
            alert(data.d);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.d);
        }
    });
```

The issue is that the SPContext is coming out null when the web method is called through this ajax code. If i put a breakpoint on the SPContext and see it's value then somehow it retrieves it and fills it in but not with no breakpoint.

Can someone help me sort this issue out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well not sure why it's doing it but if I move the SpContext.Current outside the SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() code then I can get the context loaded everytime and which solves my problem.

Comment: When you use 'RunWithElevatedPrivilegs', then you are actually created a new context so the current context will be invalid within the call